# the url requested was not found on this server

Tags: php, centos, apache-2.2

I uploaded a script called [phpmotion](http://www.phpmotion.com) to my vps, [see this](http://www.showpill.com) when you go to pretty much any page you'll see this error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /xyz was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at showpill.com Port 80
```

the .htaccess that they provide is there, everything is uploaded and installed correctly. the support team says that mod_rewrite is not enabled, but I checked and it is it enabled.

they told me to register on their forum to ask about it, I tried but it says: registration is currently disabled. Therefore I'm asking here, what would cause this problem?

**EDIT**

@George Tasioulis

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

is not commented out, i changed `AllowOverride` to `All` created a .htaccess file as you said and still did not work

**EDIT 2**

the output of `httpd -l`

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

the output of `apachectl configtest`

```
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Might want to look at upgrading your Apache.  2.2.3 was a good vintage, but it's pretty ancient at this point.

Comment: @Shane Madden - I have installed apache 2.2.21, which is the latest version but now i have another problem, first of all i wounder why am i seeing the apache test page when you go to showpill.com although my script and my index.php is still there....and then if you go to showpill/hi.php you see that apache doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you check that mod_rewrite is enabled for sure?

I would say you try this:
backup your current .htaccess file and create a new one with the following content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
  Redirect /google.html http://www.google.com
```

Now go an visit http://www.showpill.com/google.html and see if it redirects you to google.com 
If yes, then mod_rewrite works, if not check in your httpd.conf file that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` and restart Apache.

Comment: please read my edit sir

Comment: Can you please tell what 'apachectl configtest' gives you? Also please post the output of 'httpd -l'

Comment: please read my edit

Comment: I found this forum [post](http://forum.ivorde.ro/apache-2-2-installation-of-mod-rewrite-module-without-recompiling-whole-apache-t67.html) which has a guide on how to compile mod_rewrite without compiling apache from scratch. Maybe you should try that out.

Comment: would you show it to me?

Comment: The word `post` is a hyperlink to the guide. Just click the word `post` on my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

> created a .htaccess file as you said

Was there an .htaccess included with the install? Did you upload it to the server? Some FTP clients ignore dot files by default.

Comment: yes but i deleted the .htaccess to try what george said and i have write the name of the file right lol, i don't make these kind of mistakes anymore lol